# Double camera output UE4

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm new to UE4 and I'm trying to make split screen view.
[image]
It is extremely simple in Unity, but I can't find anywhere how can I do it in Unreal. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a uni student newly studying Unreal, and I'm creating a vehicle game. Vehicles are set up a bit differently from "fps shooter", or "third person character" The ways you can use split screen is; by adding player starts to your game mode blueprint.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33440183)